# Expectation from conditional expectations

Tags: self-study, conditional-probability, expected-value, conditional-expectation, bernoulli-distribution

Consider a real-valued random variable $X$ and a dichotomus random variable $Y\sim Be(p)$, all defined on the same probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$.

Could you help me to show that
$$
E(X)=E(X|Y=1)p+E(X|Y=0)(1-p)
$$

Now suppose that $X$ is a function of a real-valued continuous random variable $\epsilon$ with pdf $g(\cdot)$ and that $Y=1$ if $\epsilon\in A \subset \mathbb{R}$.

Could you help me to show the second equality of

$$
E(X(\epsilon)|Y=1)p=E(X(\epsilon)|\epsilon \in A)p=\int_{A} X(e)g(e)de
$$

Comment: HINT for the first: What possible values $Y$ can take? Also, this should possible tagged [self-study](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info)

Comment: Can you tell us where you are stuck?